# Add $(this).find to prependTo

Tags: jquery, this, prepend

I have this sentence:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'create_index'))%>").hide().prependTo(".comments_column").fadeIn(1500);
```

My html:

```
<div class="comments_column">
<div class="comment">coment 1</div>
<div class="comment">coment 2</div>
<div class="comment">coment 3</div>
<div class="comment">coment 4</div>
<div class="comment">coment 5</div>
.
.
.
<div class="comment_box">

<form method="post" action="the_action">
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Comment" class="input_comment">
</form>

</div>

</div>

<div class="comments_column"></div>
<div class="comments_column"></div>
<div class="comments_column"></div>
<div class="comments_column"></div>
<div class="comments_column"></div>
.
.
.
```

I want add **$(this).find** or this for that this sentence, only hit this **.comments_column** class, because I have a lot .comments_column in a same document.

**How working this?**

Edited. Add Html.

Comment: You only want to append it to the first `.comments_column` class? Or do you have a context, like `this`?

Comment: @minitech I have added html. I only want that working for <div class="comments_column"> that containing the form.

Comment: Are you inside the `submit` event of the `<form>`?

Comment: yes, the submit button its inside the <form> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$(".comments-column")
```

select the closest matching parent:

```
$(this).parents(".comments-column").eq(0)
```

---

**(edit)** After seeing your jsFiddle, [this is what you need to change.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/aC92Q/8/)

Comment: Thank you but how working in this sentence? `$("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'create_index'))%>").hide().prependTo(".comments_column").fadeIn(1500);`

Comment: @hyperrjas: `$("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'create_index'))%>").hide().prependTo($(this).parents(".comments-column").eq(0)).fadeIn(1500);`

Comment: @hyperrjas: Can you post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so I can test?

Comment: hello @minitech. You can see http://jsfiddle.net/aC92Q/2/. I want that hit submit button render the partial rails. The partial its a content with <div class="comment">other comment more</div> for example. Now If I click in submit button, this partial its rendered in every **comments_column**

Comment: @hyperrjas: Okay, there's a lot to change. [Here's what you want.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/aC92Q/8/)

Comment: Thank you minitech. The js effect working fine but dont save result in database. The problem is that rails send submit action before since controller. In **create.js.erb** dont work other form more. I put `<%= escape_javascript(render 'create_index')%>` under // Send your Ajax request here. I have checked too to put `<%= escape_javascript(render 'create_index')%>` in var $newComment but dont works. The problem is that submit action its create in controller and when arrive to create.js.erb we can not duplicate again submit action. Can does works without submit action? Thanks

Comment: I want rendered this partial for comment div : `<div class="comment">   
 
   
   <div class="comment_avatar"> 
       <%if current_user.avatar.present?%>
       <%= image_tag(current_user.avatar.url(:thumb)) %>
      <% else %>
       <%= image_tag(current_user.avatar.default_avatar_url_thumb)%>
      <% end %>
      </div>    
    
    
    
    <p class="user_comment_show"><%= link_to @comment.user.username, boards_users_board_path(@comment.user) %> <%= sanitize(@comment.content) %></p>
    
    </div>`

Comment: I have a text area and form with id unique. Would be possible get the id from text_area or forma and give it to the expression `$(this).parents(".comments-column").eq(0)` without submit button?. The id of text_area and form its this format: **id="text_4efcda9e1d41c82486000077"** and form **id="4efcda9e1d41c82486000077"**.

Comment: @hyperrjas: No. Do it using [Ajax](http://google.com/search?q=Ajax).

Comment: thank you for your response. How can I use ajax for get the partial `$("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'create_index'))%>")` inside last code? Thank you

Comment: @hyperrjas: I don't know Ruby on Rails, but just create an XMLHttpRequest object (with the ActiveX fallback described on tutorial sites), initialize it (again, see tutorials), and send it to a RoR controller containing only that script.

Comment: the problem its fixed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717405/unobtrusive-javascript-rails-3-1-multiple-forms-same-page