# unobtrusive javascript rails 3.1 multiple forms, same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript

**I'm crazy with multiple forms in the same page**.

every working fine when there is **one unique form** and you can identify the unique id or unique class of this form or column...etc.

But my big problem come back when I have **multiple forms in the same page**. I want rendered the partial **create_index** when I create a new comment, in **create.js.erb** I have:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render 'create_index') %>").hide().prependTo(".comments_column").fadeIn(1500);
```

The problem is that if there are many columns above forms with the class **.comments_column** the comment its rendered in every columns with the same class.

A example in jquery is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/aC92Q/8/

For rails 3.1 don't working this example. If I put that javascript in **create.js.erb**. The first time don't show the comment created.

If I put only in create.js.erb:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render 'create_index') %>").hide().prependTo(".comments_column").fadeIn(1500);
```

rendered the partial in every column that contain the class **.comments_column**.

**My question is How say to rails 3 the form or button that I am hit for render the partial only in this column?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem its fixed!. For every world that have this problem:**

Each rails UJS AJAX call provides six custom events that can be attached to:

```
ajax:before – right before ajax call
ajax:loading – before ajax call, but after XmlHttpRequest object is created)
ajax:success – successful ajax call
ajax:failure – failed ajax call
ajax:complete – completion of ajax call (after ajax:success and ajax:failure)
ajax:after – after ajax call is sent (note: not after it returns)
```

In My case I'll add an event listener to the ajax:success event on My submit button:

```
$('.comment_box form').bind('ajax:success', function() {  

   $("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'create_index'))%>").hide().prependTo($(this).parents(".comments_column").eq(0)).fadeIn(1500); 
});
```

Its very very important call the custom events or the other side dont working fine.